# Rabbitmq How to read data at once without while loop

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm reading data from RabbitMQ (java client) in this way.

```
while(true)
        {
          QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
          String message = new String(delivery.getBody());

          System.out.println(message);

        }
```

Can I read all the data in the queue without while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [the tutorials on the RabbitMQ website](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html)?

this looks like the basic java code for consuming messages:

```
Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
  @Override
  public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
  throws IOException {
    String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
      System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
  }
};

channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
```

this should send all messages to the specified consumer.

Comment: It'll give only 1 message at a time.